Material UI (MUI) React JS Data grid with pagenation. selected radio button value is removed when pagenation. any idea how to fix it
Material UI (MUI) React JS Data grid with pagination. selected radio button value is removed when pagination. any idea how to fix it. seems to be selected radio button value removed when navigate to pagination.
Selected Radio button in the data grid with pagination sorting with selected radio button is not working. it get removed when move to next page in pagination.

Please provide a code sample. It is unclear about radio button.
However, if you have selected a row and moved to the next page or have sorted a column after selecting, the row is still selected, only thing is you cannot see it. If you find that row you may see it as selected. Does this answer your question?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
